# Replacement for Dropbox datastore API?

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

As I learned today, [Dropbox Datastore API is deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/) and will stop working next April (2016).

I want to ask, is there any similar replacement, that works as key-value storage, synched with Dropbox account? Ideally with JavaScript support.

My use case is: I have a JavaScript app, I want to save a key-value storage to user's Dropbox account, I want to read it and save it back.

If the replacement is in npm/bower repositories, it would be the best.

Comment: There's a thread about alternatives here: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203479625-Dropbox-Datastore-API-Alternatives